# Storing an array in SQL and using a trigger to validate

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers

I have an assignment where we have three tables Flight, Driver and Client. There is a fourth table (Delivery) that has a field fr_ag that is a union of the flight ID, driver ID and client ID. How do these three values get stored in fr_ag? I have created a trigger to validate that a flight/driver/client exists before an entry can be created in the Delivery table, but the trigger doesn't work. For instance if I have a flight number 123, driver 456 and client 789 and try to enter 123456789 in the fr_ag field it obviously can't be found. Ideally these three data items would be stored as an array in fr_ag, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: instead of "Driver" don't you mean "Pilot"?

Answer (score 0):

Don't concatenate IDs if you can help it, and don't use triggers to validate referential constraints.

Your Delivery table can have all three columns, then you can add simple referential constraints on the columns to ensure that the flight, driver and client IDs all exist in the relevant tables.

Comment: I would have thought that to be the answer - have three columns in the Delivery table, however my assignment specs only state that we have the one column. Furthermore the database is a distributed database with local mapping transparency, therefore the use of triggers to ensure referential integrity. I guess the question is, then, how do I concatenate the IDs in SQL?

Comment: Ask whoever wrote the specs why they think a single column is the right solution.